# Closing an application and saving data when using ARC Welder

Tags: google-chrome-arc

When closing an application using ARC Welder, does the application get any message about this?

There are methods like `OnPause` / `OnStop` / `OnDestroy`. They are called by Android OS, but in our opinion they are not called by ARC Welder when we close an application. So the data can't be saved this way and the user would have to save all data manually before closing the application.

Comment: They appear to be called if the user presses the BACK button in the title bar, as part of normal activity teardown. They are not called if the user closes the window. And, from the initial activity, the user *has* no BACK button.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it looks like we do currently not forward the signal we receive from the chrome.app.window.onClosed event.

Feel free to [star this bug](http://crbug.com/400738) to vote it up.